# C++ Calling a function from the header file in the main

Tags: c++, function, header, scope, inheritance

I'm writing an integral calculator. I'm trying to get the main.cpp file to read in the functions from the functions class which is in the functions.h.cpp files. I have a function defined as the following for the easy case:

```
double square(double aX)
 {
   return aX*aX;
 }
```

This function works when I include it in the main file, though it doesn't want to work when I try and call it from the main file when it's in the functions file. Here is the code that I have:

`Main.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntegralCalculator.h"
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
  {
    IntegralCalculator Function(square);
    Function.print();
  }
```

As you can see, there is another class called `IntegralCalculator` which actually does the calculation of the integral, though nothing should be wrong with that as it works when the function definition is included in the main, and the function is passed as a parameter. The `functions.h` file is defined as the following:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "IntegralCalculator.h"


class functions : public IntegralCalculator
 {
  public:
   functions();
   double square(double aX);

 };

#endif
```

and the `functions.cpp` file is defined as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "functions.h"


double functions::square(double aX)
 {
   return aX*aX;
 }
```

I know that as of right now I don't need the `<cmath>` library, though I'm going to need it for more complicated functions when I add them.

I have tried inheriting the functions class in the main, and I have tried creating a namespace for the functions class and defining the function, however none of these have worked. When I go to compile, I get the following error:

`Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`

`Main.cpp:9: error: ‘square’ was not declared in this scope`

If someone could please help me figure out this problem. This code that I'm trying to write is more advanced than my class has gone over, so I'm not sure how to fix it, though I want to write the program this way.

Edit: In case you were curious, I am including the `functions.h` and `functions.cpp` files in the Makefile. I was getting the same error when I was trying to put the `square(double aX)` definition in the `IntegralCalculator` class as well.

Comment: Did you declare `double square(double aX)` in `functions.h`?

Comment: If you look at the section where I have the `functions.h` file, you can see that I do.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you declared the square function in the functions class, thus making it a member function, you have to declare it as double functions::square(double ax){...}

Comment: @RaduChivu Forgot to put that part in the post. I do have it though and I get the same error.

Comment: What is definition of `IntegralCalculator::IntegralCalculator(????)` (the constrcutor)?

Comment: Did you also declare the function header in the functions.h file and forgot to add it?, you should also have a double square(double ax); somewhere in there

Comment: @RaduChivu I have `double square(double aX);` declared in the header file. And it was included in the original post, unless I'm miss understanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: @hyde The constructor is defined as the following          `IntegralCalculator::IntegralCalculator(double aIntegrandFunction(double))`


`{
  userInput(); //return character here
  calcIntegral(aIntegrandFunction); //return
}`

Comment: you have the square function included as a member function in the functions class, if you want to have the square function as a standalone function not linked to the class, there should be two definitions, one for the member function and one outside the class functions {...} block for the global function

Comment: @RaduChivu I moved the function declaration outside of the `functions` class block, though now I'm getting the following error: `functions.cpp:6: error: no ‘double functions::square(double)’ member function declared in class ‘functions’`

Which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: you don't want  to move it you need both declarations, they are different functions

Comment: why does `class functions` inherit IntegralCalculator? Is there a reason, is it just random code with no purpose?

Comment: @hyde. It's random code with no purpose. I was going to try to make the code more complicated, though I changed it and forgot to remove that part of the code.

Comment: It is unfortunately decreasingly rare that the question *and* this ensuing stream of comments is actually more confusing than the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig You should make a suggestion for threaded comments at meta, that would help ;)

Comment: @user1560300 My answer seems to be ok now, it had some bad errors for a while, which I just finished fixing (just saying if you wondered WTF, or especially in case you didn't notice anything funny...).

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is, `square` is a member function AKA method. In other words, there is no plain symbol `square` anywhere, it's `functions::square`. And because it is not a static method, it makes no sense alone, it always needs a corresponding object instance, which you do not have and which `IntegralCalculator` couldn't use even if you did.

3 solutions, in the order of simplest, closest to your question, best:

---

From the constructor delcaration, move the `square` out of the class, make it a global function:

In functions.h outside any class:

```
double square(double aX);
```

In functions.cpp

```
double square(double aX) {
    return aX*aX;
}
```

Usage in main.cpp:

```
IntegralCalculator Function(square);
```

---

Or make it static method (which is how you would have to do if you used a language like Java, which didn't allow "naked" functions, but is not really C++ way):

in functions.h:

```
class functions // inheriting IntegralCalculator removed as not needed
{
    public:
    static double square(double aX);
};
```

and in functions.cpp:

```
//static
double functions::square(double aX) {
    return aX*aX;
}
```

Then you can pass it like this to `Function constructor in main.cpp:

```
IntegralCalculator Function(functions::square);
```

---

Finally, perhaps the best solution, sort of combining the best of the two above: put `square` in a namespace. So functions.h becomes

```
namespace functions {
    double square(double aX)
}
```

functions.cpp becomes

```
namespace functions {
    double square(double aX) {
        return aX*aX;
    }
}
```

You still use it in main like this:

```
IntegralCalculator Function(functions::square);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
class functions : public IntegralCalculator
 {
  public:
   functions();
   double square(double aX);

 };
```

which is ok, but doesn't tell other cpp files that there is a global function called square somewhere in your functions.cpp file.
What you need to do is include the header for that function so that the compiler knows that it exists:

```
double square(double ax);
class functions : public IntegralCalculator
 {
  public:
   functions();
   double square(double aX);

 };
```

Also completely unrelated to your question, but worth mentioning after seeing your constructor code, you might want to use a typedef to declare the function pointer like so:

```
typedef double (IntegralFunctor*)(double);
```

So that your constructor can now be

```
IntegralCalculator::IntegralCalculator(IntegralFunctor func);
```

It's cleaner and less confusing this way